# Mobile nav not working correctly on Safari

Tags: javascript, css, nav

I have two separate nav bars for mobile and desktop, the one on mobile has a hamburger icon and when clicked, a semi-transparent black overlay slides down from the top and displays the links. On Google Chrome, this works perfectly fine, but on Safari for some reason the overlay only drops down to the height of the navbar. Here's the URL to the website, set it to mobile size and try the menu in Safari. Any ideas? Thanks!

bodytone.samileier.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on `#navbar`, remove the `overflow: hidden` property

```
#navbar {
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 60px rgba(0,0,0,0.08);
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}
```

Comment: This definitely fixed the issue! However now my navbar doesn't stick to the top on scroll..is there a way to keep the position relative and somehow make the nav fixed to the top? Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @SamiLeier Apologies, I misunderstood the requirement there. I've edited my answer to achieve both